# Exclude the restangular functions from received object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

How can i Exclude the restangular functions from object i received. Thus here, the properties starting with "addRestangularMethod" should be excluded. If possible, while receiving.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude all the restangular additional stuff by calling `.plain()` on your response. [The documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) has this:

> plain(): Returns the plain element received from the server without
>   any of the enhanced methods from Restangular. It's an alias to calling
>   Restangular.stripRestangular(elem)